# Is there a way to enable intellisense autocomplete in quotes without using key binding (Ctrl + Space) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: autocomplete, intellisense, vscode-extensions

I want to develop an extension for Visual Studio Code.
I'v registered a CompletionItemProvider for typescript, when I'm trying to write in quotes the auto completion does not work.
For example I have this code:

```
function buildProvider(language : vscode.DocumentSelector, label : string, text : string | vscode.CompletionItemLabel){
return vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('typescript', {
    provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position, token: vscode.CancellationToken, context: vscode.CompletionContext) {

        const simpleCompletion = new vscode.CompletionItem('', vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);

        simpleCompletion.label = label;
        simpleCompletion.insertText = text.toString();

        return [
            simpleCompletion,
        ];
    }
});
```

}

If I write in typescript the auto completion work:

[Auto completion works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGSvT.png)

If I write in quotes it doesn't work without using Ctrl + Space.

[Auto completion does not works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukyCc.png)

What can I do to enable the auto completion in quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behaviour, not working in strings, is probably a result of the setting:

`editor.quickSuggestions`.

Try setting it like this:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
  "other": true,
  "comments": false,
  "strings": true                 // this is the key setting, default is false3
}
```

That will fix it for you or anyone with the same `"strings": true` setting.

You can change a user's default settings in an extension like this in your `package.json - beware they may not like you changing their settings!!:

````
> #### Configuration Defaults Overrides
> 
> 
> You can now override defaults of other registered configurations
> through `configurationDefaults` contribution point in `package.json`.
> For example, the following snippet overrides the default behavior of
> `files.autoSave` setting to auto save files on focus change.

```jsonc
"contributes": {
  "configurationDefaults": {                 // applies to all languages
      "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange"
  }
}
````

> Note: Configurations with application or machine scopes cannot be
> overridden.

- From https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#configuration-defaults-overrides